# How can I save multiple categories checkboxes in an array json object in React

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am building a page to create post where user can select multiple categories,

I am having the problem when I am sending the data with the post request with multiple categories object, I am unable to collect the multiple category ids in single object to send with other data.

**Default states**

```
constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        menuItems: [],
        shortDescription: '',
        body: RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue(),
        metaDescription: ''
    };
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
}
```

**On changed handler for other fields**

```
onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name] : value
    })
}
```

**Category change handler which is returning new array object of each category id**

```
categoryChangeHandler = (e, data) => {
    let selectedMenuItems = {
        categoryId: data.value,
    }
    console.log(selectedMenuItems);
}
```

**Fetching list of categories from the api**

```
{this.state.menuItems.map((menuItem) =>
    <Grid.Column key={menuItem.id} width={4}>
        <Checkbox label={menuItem.title} name={menuItem.title} 
        key={menuItem.id} 
        value={menuItem.id}
        onChange={(e, data) => this.categoryChangeHandler(menuItem.key, data)} />
    </Grid.Column>
)}
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear, do you want to send menuItems array in a post request or you want to create another array to send in the post request? If yes to later, have you created this new array/object in the state? Also, are you having problem sending the Post request or are you having an issue collecting the data in the state?

Comment: I am having a problem with the data collection

Answer (score 0):

You could write a separate checkbox change handler that stores all your checkbox values in one JSON object in your state.

```
handleCheckBoxChange(e) {
        const tempState = {
            checkboxValues: {
                ...this.state.checkboxValues,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
            }
        }
        this.setState(tempState)
    }
```

example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/312818/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new property in your state to collect the checkbox data, e.g selectedMenuItems:

```
    constructor (props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        title: '',
        menuItems: [],
        shortDescription: '',
        selectedMenuItems: [], //new property
        body: RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue(),
        metaDescription: ''
     };
     this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this); //you don't need this line as you are using and arrow function
}
```

Then make the following changes in your change handler:

```
categoryChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    let selectedMenu = this.state.selectedMenuItems;
    selectedMenu[name] = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({
       selectedMenuItems : selectedMenu
    });
}
```

Then finally call this handler like this:

```
{this.state.menuItems.map((menuItem) =>
    <Grid.Column key={menuItem.id} width={4}>
        <Checkbox label={menuItem.title} name={menuItem.title} 
        key={menuItem.id} 
        value={menuItem.id}
        onChange={this.categoryChangeHandler} />
    </Grid.Column>
)}
```

Its advisable to not to use arrow function directly in the render function as it creates a new function every time the component is rendered. This may cause performance issues.